# Python Explanation

Tags: python, foreach

Can someone please explain how this works? The output equals 10 but I want to understand how it comes to that answer.

```
count = 10
item = 0
for each in range(count):
    item += each
    count -= each
print(item + count)
```

Answer (score 3):

In the end you've subtracted the same amount from count as you added to item. `(+45) + (-45) = 0`. You can see it in action with a print statement

```
count = 10
item = 0
for each in range(count):
    item += each
    count -= each
    print('interim:', 'item', item, 'count', count, 'sum', item+count)
print(item + count)
```

results in

```
interim: item 0 count 10 sum 10
interim: item 1 count 9 sum 10
interim: item 3 count 7 sum 10
interim: item 6 count 4 sum 10
interim: item 10 count 0 sum 10
interim: item 15 count -5 sum 10
interim: item 21 count -11 sum 10
interim: item 28 count -18 sum 10
interim: item 36 count -26 sum 10
interim: item 45 count -35 sum 10
10
```

Answer (score 1):

Your loop iterates over every number between 1-10.
It is returning what number it is currently on in `each` (which is a bad variable name)
Then for every iteration it increments `item` (which starts at 0) and decrements `count` (which starts at 10, and is also how your loop knows to count to 10).

count+item will always equal 10 because:

`10+0=10
9+1=10
8+2=10`

etc.

Comment: Thanks. I see it now... just didn't understand how it looped